# play framework help in views

Tags: java, scala, frameworks, playframework

While writing the javatodolist application for Play, I get an error from part "The application template"

`reference to Form is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by import play.data._ and import play.api.data._`

My `index.scala.html` is at http://nopaste.info/f10c386a02.html

And [here is the error](http://oi44.tinypic.com/dw6uf5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The exception that you printed

> reference to Form is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by import play.data._ and import play.api.data._

means that there are two classes with name Form one under package **play.data._**  , the other one under the package **play.api.data._**
I would recommend that you explicitly do your imports that means import just classes you would use.

Answer (score 0):

Play Framework offers a Java and Scala API. Clearly, you want the Scala API, but it looks like you've added both to your classpath and imported both.

[Here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/api/java/index.html?play/data/Form.html) is the Java version of `Form` in the `play.data` package.
[Here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form) is the Scala version of `Form` in the `play.data.api` package.

Get rid of the Java stuff, and you should be fine.

Comment: I have tried to removed one of imports. Either way, its throwing me exact same error.

Comment: So you got the exact same "imported twice" error when you are only importing once?

Comment: Exactly. I tried to remove both of my imports and I'm still getting the same error. "imported twice"

Probably, this is because i'm using the development version of play-2.2.2-RC1.zip. I will try to use 2.2.1 probably its more stable. I will let you know if this would fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, i have tried it using 2.2.1, and its giving me exact same error. I'm not importing but I get error saying

reference to Form is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by import play.data._ and import

Comment: Sadly, that's what I expected. Something strange is going on with your environment. I can't say what. Just make sure you aren't placing the Java API and the Scala API on the classpath. I worry that something strange could be going on with implicit conversions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just would like to ask if my code in index.scala.html working in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

After having read the comments appended to the question, I got it working by qualifying the version of Form the view needs (the one from play.data) as in the following example:

```
@(myForm: play.data.Form[form.MyFormClass])
```

I guess that this behaviour is due to the fact that I am developing a Play application in java while the views are using the Scala API.